# Prove exponent law $a^{m+n} = a^m a^n$ for rational exponents

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I was thinking about why $a^m* a^n = a^{m+n}$.
I was able to reach a logical argument by firstly proving it for natural numbers, then extending it to rational numbers by writing powers as $p/q$ where p and q are integers, and then for irrational numbers by limiting them to a rational equivalent.
But then in my argument I used the fact that $(a^m)^n = a^{mn}$.
I am unable to think of a proof why it must be true for all rational numbers.

I am familiar with the idea of using logarithms but the I believe logarithmic properties are proved with the help of laws of indices only(which I am trying to prove).
Thank you.

Comment: This is surely a dupe but I don't have time to complete the search at the moment.

Comment: What is your definition of $a^{p/q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are integers, $q\neq 0$? Do you put restrictions on the exponents? On the basis? On the exponent dependingo n the basis? Proving things requires precise definitions.

Comment: $0^{2-1} \ne 0^2\times 0^{-1}$